# Calling Java method from C++

Tags: java, c++

Could someone please help me with the below-mentioned query:

What would be the most **efficient** way/mechanism to call a java function from C++
The Java function is on one JVM, and the C++ is another program altogether
Both programs residing on the same machine

java function could be either:

-returns an array of chars
-Or returns a String
-Or returns a double

Comment: You could set-up a local socket connection between your processes and communicate through it

Comment: Yes, I did some research based on your answer. And it's quite helpful!

Comment: @Quanta Also, I think protocol buffers would be an efficient way too, right? Would love to know your thoughts on the same